# How do you resolve Git conflicts in yarn.lock

Tags: javascript, git, npm, yarnpkg

When multiple Git branches modify the dependencies in a project that uses [Yarn](http://yarnpkg.com), it is likely to introduce a conflict in the yarn.lock file. It is not a good idea to delete and regenerate the yarn.lock file because this will probably cause several packages to be unintentionally upgraded. What is the best way to quickly resolve conflicts in this file?

Answer (score 335, accepted):

[Since Yarn 1.0](https://code.facebook.com/posts/274518539716230) it's easy because it has built in support for this scenario.

First solve the conflict in `package.json` manually, then just run this:

```
$ yarn install

yarn install v1.0.1
info Merge conflict detected in yarn.lock and successfully merged.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
```

And then the conflict will be resolved and you can commit that or continue rebasing if that was what you were doing.

Comment: I don't believe this works if there are conflicts in your `yarn.lock` containing lines of code such as `============`, `>>>>>>>>>>>>>>`, `<<<<<<<<<<<<<`. You still need to do what Christine Schlensker's answer talks about.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage don't believe it, try it

Comment: Doesn't work, throws `error An unexpected error occurred: "Unknown token 7713:1 in /location`

Comment: Works for me


    `16:23 $ yarn`
    `yarn install v1.7.0`
    `info Merge conflict detected in yarn.lock and successfully merged.`

Comment: you need to fix your conflicts in package.json first then run yarn and it should handle it

Comment: Worked liked charm.

Comment: It printed out the "successfully merged" message for me but the yarn.lock still contained the merge conflicts.

Comment: this works but webstorm shows still as it is conflicted, how to mark it as resolved?

Comment: This did not work for me with yarn 1.22.17. As @theGreenCabbage says the conflicts still remain in the yarn.lock. There are no conflicts in my package.json.

Comment: @rsobies just run in terminal `git add yarn.lock`

Comment: delete yarn.lock and do a freah yarn install with packages mentioned in package.json

Comment: This doesn't work if there are no conflicts in `package.json`

Comment: @JESii If you have a conflict in yarn.lock without a change in package.json there's something wrong in your workflow. You shouldn't touch yarn.lock without changing the version in package.json

Comment: @vanuan it can happen if you are cherry-picking or rebasing several version updates to packages that are not on adjacent lines in package.json (so git easily merges them) but they both mess with deeper dependencies that conflict in yarn.lock, which git can't natively resolve.

Comment: For those using rails, `yarn install --check-files` did fix the merge conflicts, but I'd still get an error saying my yarn packages were out of date.  Deleting the `node_modules` folder and then running `yarn install --check-files` fixes things.

Comment: This doesn't work even if you do have conflicts in `package.json`. It just complains that `package.json` has invalid JSON due to `<<<`/`>>>`/`===`.

Comment: @Vanuan lockfile contents are not deterministic from `package.json` contents. The same `package.json` can generate two different lockfiles if you run the install at different times.

Answer (score 94):

A good approach is detailed in [this github discussion](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1776#issuecomment-269539948) about the issue.

> ```
> git rebase origin/master
> ```
>
> When the first conflict arises, I checkout
>   the `yarn.lock` then re-perform the installation
>
> ```
> git checkout origin/master -- yarn.lock 
> yarn install
> ```
>
> This generates a
>   new `yarn.lock` based on the origin/master version of yarn.lock, but
>   including the changes I made to my `package.json`. Then it's just a matter of:
>
> ```
> git add yarn.lock
> git rebase --continue
> ```

Comment: For this and the accepted answer, I have to repeat the commands multiple times and git ends up with the following:


```No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.```

Comment: My fix ended being these steps on a regular merge - It never worked on my rebase.

Answer (score 0):

If ‘yarn install’ doesn’t helped

```
1) git checkout <target branch>
2) git pull
3) git checkout <our branch with conflict>
4) git merge <target branch> (you will see merge conflict on yarn.lock)
5) rm yarn.lock
6) yarn
7) git add yarn.lock
8) git commit -m
9) git push
```

Comment: i'd be careful with deleting the lock file. this will throw away any locked versions and you will most likely end up with versions of packages you have never tested in integration before.

Answer (score -7):

this file is too long so if you need to check conflict in vscode without terminal maybe you can try a search in this file for terms like: `>>>>>>>`, `=======`, `<<<<<<<` or `HEAD`