# WebStorm and resolving conflicts in yarn.lock

Tags: git, webstorm, yarnpkg

After reading [How do you resolve git conflicts in yarn.lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939113/how-do-you-resolve-git-conflicts-in-yarn-lock) I tried to run `yarn install` to resolve conflicts in yarn.lock file, it worked, no conflicts in files, great... but WebStorm still shows it as conflicted.

I wonder how can I mark those files as resolved? There is a window for conflict resolving but I can only chose "accept theirs/yours".

Comment: I guess the missing step would be running `git add yarn.lock`?

Comment: great, it works :)